# Simple functions in $L^{1}(X)$ are dense in $L^{1}(X)$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $A= \lbrace \phi \in L^{1}(X) \: | \: \phi \: \mbox{is simple}  \rbrace$. Prove $A$ is dense in $L^{1}(X)$. Basically my idea is to prove that  for every $f \in L^{1}(X)$  and  every $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\phi \in A$ such $||f-\phi||_{1}< \epsilon $ in other words  there is $\phi \in A$ contained in every neighborhood of $f \in L^{1}(X)$.

But $||f-\phi||_{1}< \epsilon $ means that $\int |f-\phi| d \mu < \epsilon $. So how can I prove this las inequality for every $\epsilon>0$. Thanks!!

In this answer [Simple functions are dense in L1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1760500/simple-functions-are-dense-in-l1)

I dont know why $$
\int |f^+-\varphi^+|\,d\mu<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\text{ and }\int |f^--\varphi^-|\,d\mu<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}
$$for any $\varepsilon>0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually one approximates $f^{+}$ by a simple function $\phi$：
\begin{align*}
\int|f^{+}-\varphi|<\epsilon/2,
\end{align*}
and then approximates $f^{-}$ with another one $\psi$:
\begin{align*}
\int|f^{-}-\psi|<\epsilon/2,
\end{align*}
then $\varphi+\psi$ is a simple function that approximates $f=f^{+}-f^{-}$:
\begin{align*}
\int|f-(\varphi+\psi)|=\int|(f^{+}-\varphi)+(f^{-}-\psi)|\leq\int|f^{+}-\varphi|+\int|f^{-}-\psi|<\epsilon.
\end{align*}

For nonnegative function $g$, we have by definition that
\begin{align*}
\int g=\sup\left\{\int\phi: 0\leq\phi\leq g\right\},
\end{align*}
where $\phi$ is any simple function, so $\displaystyle g$ can be approximated by some $0\leq\phi\leq g$ by arbitrary small:
\begin{align*}
\int g-\int\phi<\epsilon,
\end{align*}
but then $|g-\phi|=g-\phi$ because $\phi\leq g$, so 
\begin{align*}
\int|g-\phi|=\int g-\int\phi<\epsilon.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks a lot but it is precisely the first two line of your proof why I cannot end up understanding the whole proof. I mean, Why there is a simple function  $\phi$  for every $f^{+}$ such $\int|f^{+}-\varphi|<\epsilon/2$ ? @user284331

Comment: I have used the result that for nonnegative function, one can approximate it by a simple function in $L^{1}$, this is proved in the link that you pasted there.

Comment: But still dont know how in the posted link, why $\int |f^+-\varphi^+|\,d\mu<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\text{ and }\int |f^--\varphi^-|\,d\mu<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$? In the proof there it is mentioned this fact is trivial but still dont know why? :/

Comment: I have added the details, it should be clear now.

Comment: All clear now! Apreciate it! @user284331