# Is density of simple functions immediate according to this definition of an integral?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Consider the following defintion of an integral

[image]

I would like to establish that

> given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $g$ simple such that
>
> $$ \int_E |f-g| d \mu \leq \epsilon. $$

By definition I know that I can find $g$ such that
$$
\left| \int_E f - \int_E g \right| < \epsilon.
$$
However, the result seems to be much stronger.

**Question:** Is the fact I wish to prove something trivial or done one need more machinery to prove it?

Comment: Is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1760500) a duplicate? Your fact is trivial for purely nonnegative or nonpositive functions (well, and given the machinery of the additivity of Lebesgue integration)

Comment: It's trivial. Reread the definition, closely.

Comment: You have simple $g$ s.t. $\left| \int_E f - \int_E g \right| < \epsilon$ and $g \leq f$. This make taking absoulte value under integral redundant.

Comment: I am completely blind. I missed the fact that $g \leq f$. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the definition, the requirement $g \leq f$ gives the required result.